# How To Add User Defined Attribute in PIP Attribute User Store

Tags: wso2, xacml3, wso2-identity-server

Hi I am working with WSO2 Balana Xacml 3.0 . I want to add my own attribute called Customer in the attribute store dynamically how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add new attribute called "Customer" in to the attribute store? Sorry,  Balana does not contain an attribute store. It can contain only the attribute finder modules that would takes to attribute store and retrieve them. You can find the sample implementations of Balana PIP attribute finder module from [here](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/balana/modules/balana-samples/kmarket-trading-sample/src/main/java/org/wso2/balana/samples/kmarket/trading/SampleAttributeFinderModule.java). You can see that attribute id called "http://kmarket.com/id/role" has been registered with the PIP module

Comment: Thanks Asela, so you mean to say we can register Attributes from PIP, but if Balana contains attribute finder modules and it will take me to attribute store it means some where attribute store is there. how i can add my own attribute.

Comment: Yes..  we can register the attribute Id that are supported by given PIP. Then PDP knows what attribute id are supported from each PIP. And call the PIP once, it is needed.

Comment: So if i understood correctly from your sample code you are registering new attribute to the attribute store using PIP.
    @Override
    public Set getSupportedIds() {
        Set<String> ids = new HashSet<String>();
        ids.add("http://kmarket.com/id/role");
        return ids;   
    }

Comment: yes... It is a PIP extension, It register a new attribute Id called "http://kmarket.com/id/role" ..  So this PIP know how to resolve this attribute id. Basically it knows to retrieve attribute from some attribute source for given  "http://kmarket.com/id/role" attribute id

Comment: can you please guide me for this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479622/how-to-manage-trust-between-pep-and-pdp